# Foreground audio recoder not recording on worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to create an audio recorder that runs as a foreground service, and since I do not want to block my UI Thread, I have created a worker thread in my `AudioRecorderService` class. But I am facing two issues:

1. When I run recorder from within the worker thread, it is not working properly as it stores a blank mp4 file. However, if I run it on UI Thread, it works fine.
2. When my app is in background and I access my app from notification drawer, it restarts the activity, in the sense that my timer displays "0:00" not the elapsed time and the record button is set to its original state.

My AudioRecorderService class code is as follows:

```
public class AudioRecorderService extends Service {

    private MediaRecorder mAudioRecorder;
    private String fileName;
    private Thread thread;

    public AudioRecorderService() {
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/" + "test.mp4";

                if (mAudioRecorder == null) {
                    mAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                    mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(256);
                    mAudioRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
                    mAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                    mAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
                }

                try {
                    mAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    mAudioRecorder.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                if (thread.isInterrupted()) {
                    if (mAudioRecorder != null) {
                        mAudioRecorder.stop();
                        mAudioRecorder.release();
                        mAudioRecorder = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        //Setup Notification
        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        final Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Audio Recorder")
                .setContentText("Click to Access Audio Recorder")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {

            thread.interrupt();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Logcat Error Messages:

```
06-20 00:34:45.618 28132-28132/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.e.a
06-20 00:34:46.026 28132-28132/? E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null
06-20 00:34:49.945 736-736/? E/Launcher: onNewIntent: intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
06-20 00:35:09.559 28441-28441/? E/Gallery2/MovieActivity: NFC not available!
06-20 00:35:09.887 137-1726/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [0]
06-20 00:35:09.898 137-1726/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [0]
06-20 00:35:09.898 137-1726/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [0]
06-20 00:35:09.932 136-136/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: parseDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [0]
06-20 00:35:09.932 136-136/? E/DrmMtkPlugIn: onOpenDecryptSession() : failed to parse dcf file.
06-20 00:35:09.972 137-1726/? E/FlvExtractor: [ERROR]:Not an FLV file!!!
06-20 00:35:09.972 137-1726/? E/FlvExtractor: [ERROR]:[FLV]mtk_flv_extractor_recognize OUT
06-20 00:35:09.972 137-1726/? E/DataSource: SniffFLV return 0
06-20 00:35:09.977 137-1726/? E/MediaPlayerService:   error: -2147483648
06-20 00:35:09.977 28441-28441/? E/MediaPlayer: Unable to to create media player
06-20 00:35:09.977 28441-28453/? E/MediaPlayer: error (262, 0)
06-20 00:35:10.239 28441-28441/? E/MediaPlayer: Error (262,0)
06-20 00:35:10.973 28441-28441/? E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
06-20 00:35:11.730 736-736/? E/Launcher: onNewIntent: intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
06-20 00:35:16.985 137-457/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] def.nBufferSize = 8192
06-20 00:35:16.985 137-457/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] totalSize = 16384
06-20 00:35:30.973 803-1055/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
06-20 00:35:30.982 803-1055/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: Sorted scan results
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 48:ee:0c:1c:d6:ce freq=2417 qual=0 noise=0 level=-29 flags=0xb
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0007442d4c696e6b50010882848b960c1218240301022a010032043048606c2d1a6e181fffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d16020000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a0e14000a00b400c8001400050019007f0101dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20401000050f20230140100000fac020100000fac040100000fac020000dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd1e00904c336e181fffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dd1a00904c3402000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dd0600e04c020160
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: Beacon IEs
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0007442d4c696e6b50010882848b960c1218240301020504000100002a010432043048606c2d1a6e181fffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d16020000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a0e14000a00b400c8001400050019007f0101dd160050f20101000050f20201000050f20401000050f20230140100000fac020100000fac040100000fac020000dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd1e00904c336e181fffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dd1a00904c3402000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dd0600e04c020160
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 00:17:7c:3a:59:56 freq=2437 qual=0 noise=0 level=-68 flags=0xb
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 000d2a2a2a2a76697275732a2a2a2a010882848b960c1218240301062a010032043048606c30140100000fac020100000fac020100000fac020000dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd0600e04c020160
06-20 00:35:31.686 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: Beacon IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 000d2a2a2a2a76697275732a2a2a2a010882848b960c1218240301060504000100002a010432043048606c30140100000fac020100000fac020100000fac020000dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd0600e04c020160
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: e4:f4:c6:43:dc:88 freq=2412 qual=0 noise=0 level=-74 flags=0x2b
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 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
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0c:d2:b5:60:63:5c freq=2447 qual=0 noise=0 level=-87 flags=0xb
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0015547972696f6e2077696c6c20646965206e6578742e010882848b961224486c03010832040c18306007064d5820010b143308200102030405060733082105060708090a0b05040001001add1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f2022a01042d1a6e1117ff000000010000000000000000000000000c00000000003d16080000000000000000000000000000000000000000004a0e14000a002c01c8001400050019007f0101dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd07000c4304000000
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0c:d2:b5:46:4d:40 freq=2462 qual=0 noise=0 level=-88 flags=0xb
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 00064d756b657368010882848b961224486c03010b2a010432040c1830602d1a6e1117ff000000010000000000000000000000000c00000000003d160b0006000000000000000000000000000000000000003e0100dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202dd180050f2020101000003a5000027a4000042435e0062322f004a0e14000a002c01c8001400050019007f0101dd07000c430400000007064d5820010b10
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: Beacon IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 00064d756b657368010882848b961224486c03010b32040c18306007064d5820010b143308200102030405060733082105060708090a0b050400010000dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f2022a01042d1a6e1117ff000000010000000000000000000000000c00000000003d160b0006000000000000000000000000000000000000004a0e14000a002c01c8001400050019007f0101dd180050f2020101000003a5000027a4000042435e0062322f00dd07000c4304000000
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 0c:d2:b5:3f:b7:04 freq=2447 qual=0 noise=0 level=-89 flags=0xb
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: IEs
06-20 00:35:31.687 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: 001041697274656c5f5a65726f746f756368010882848b961224486c0301082a010432040c1830602d1a6e1117ff000000010000000000000000000000000c00000000003d16080406000000000000000000000000000000000000003e0100dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202dd180050f2020101000003a4000027a4000042435e0062322f004a0e14000a002c01c8001400050019007f0101dd07000c430400000007064d5820010b10
06-20 00:35:31.726 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: WPS: WFA subelement id=0 len=1
06-20 00:35:31.726 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: WPS: WFA subelement id=0 len=1
06-20 00:35:31.726 595-595/? E/wpa_supplicant: WPS: WFA subelement id=0 len=1
06-20 00:35:42.021 28679-28834/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53324070 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x53323a48 arg=0x0
06-20 00:35:42.021 28679-28705/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53324308 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x52e84a48 arg=0x0
06-20 00:35:42.021 28679-28834/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53324070 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
06-20 00:35:42.022 28679-28705/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53324308 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Please help!!!

Comment: How have you registered the Service in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i have. If i do not create worker thread and runs the recorder on UI Thread, it works fine. Though notification drawer issue still persists. @Micah Simmons

Comment: I said * "How have you registered the Service in your manifest? " *, I didn't say "have you registered the service in your manifest?"

Comment: Oops! my bad. Here is how: `<service
            android:name=".AudioRecorderService"
            android:exported="false"></service>`

Comment: Try changing `android:exported="false"` to `android:exported="true"`

Comment: no still no luck. It shows this error message in logcat: `E/MediaPlayer: Unable to to create media player`

Comment: Post more of that error message in the logcat, how you're starting the service, and where you're saving the data in your quesiton

Comment: I am starting the service using a button. And saving it in Music folder in External Storage. I have added complete error logcat. @Micah Simmons.